# Is it possible to mark a method with a route in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

It's possible to subclass `Flask`:

```
from flask import Flask

class MyServer(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def my_cool_method(self):
        print("About to do some crazy productive work!")
```

By doing this, one could create a `MyServer` object and define a route which, when hit, calls a method.

```
my_server = MyServer(__name__)

@my_server.route("/my_cool_endpoint")
def my_cool_endpoint():
    my_server.my_cool_method()
```

Is there any possible way to cut out this seemingly unnecessary (and fairly unsustainable) step and simply decorate a *method* with a route?

My pseudocode would be something like...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask

class MyServer(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @self.route("/my_cool_endpoint")
    def my_cool_method(self):
        print("About to do some crazy productive work!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_server = MyServer(__name__)
    # We can now hit 127.0.0.1:8080/my_cool_endpoint... hopefully
    my_server.run(port=8080)
```

My motivation is to simply `run` the object and let the endpoints get hit, modifying the state of the object on each API call.

If this isn't possible exactly as I've described, what's the least offensive way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's kinda hard to understand. Why doesn't simple controllers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`route` is a method of the `Flask` class, so it actually needs the app instance as the first argument (which gets passed in when you do `@app.route`). Since all methods (decorated or not) of a class get evaluated at "compile" time, it cannot be done the way you describe (or can be, but require some serious magic). You can always do:

```
class MyApp(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count = 0
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        @self.route('/')
        def index():
            self.count += 1
            print self.count
            return 'foo'
```

`self` can reference the same `self` as in `__init__`, due to the closure formed.

But keeping state in objects in Flask is not that good, due to Flask's [context locals](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/local/). Use sessions instead.

Also, I think what you seek is [class-based views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/views/)